# Ember Data EmbeddedRecordsMixin won't save newly created records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm using Ember Data 1.13.7 and Ember 1.13.6 with ActiveModelSerializer and EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

I have 2 models:

```
// models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  //bunch of attrs
  commentStuff: DS.belongsTo('commentStuff', {async:true})
}
```

and

```
//models/comment-stuff.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  //bunch of attrs
  post: DS.belongsTo('post', {async: true))
}
```

in my serializer I have

```
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,

  attrs: {
    commentStuff: {serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'ids'}
  },

  keyForAttribute(attr){
    if(attr === 'commentStuff'){
      return 'comment_stuff_attributes';
    } else {
      return this._super(attr);
    }
  }

});
```

This works perfectly when I edit existing records and then `post.save()` but when I create new records with:

```
var post = this.store.createRecord('post');
post.commentStuff = this.store.createRecord('commentStuff');
```

And then fill in all their respective attributes. The json sent to the server on `post.save()` shows none of the `commentStuff` attributes and just returns `null`.

```
{post: {
  attribute1: 'whatever',
  attribute2: 'smth',
  attribute3: 4,
  comment_stuff_attributes: null}
}
```

Is there a different way I should be saving/creating new records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.set` and `.get` methods. Not `post.commentStuff =`, but `post.set('commentStuff',`.

Comment: <3 Thank you so much! Because Ember Inspector *seemed* to know the related records I assumed that part probably wasn't the problem. I'm so relieved!